# Xpath get the text while there is another tags inside?

Tags: xpath

I want to extract some string, but there are other tags beside that string, here's the example

```
<p class="price"> 
    <del>52.100</del>
    26.100         
</p>
```

i want to get only the 26.100, how the xpath handle this?

i've try using this, but i still get two value, blank and the text

```
//p[@class="price"]/text()
```

is there another expression to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
//p[@class='price']/text()[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//p[@class='price']/text()[normalize-space(.)!='']
```

`text()[normalize-space(.)!='']` means to get text nodes that contain text other than spaces and hard returns.